# Bypass "NoneType" object o attribution 'content'

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am practicing **scraping** the webpage - 'Rotten Tomato' using Beautiful Soup. However, I am encountering a problem, it seems like not all movies's have a box_office number or runtime, so when I try to run my code, there is a "AttributeError", saying 'NoneType. Is there a way I can bypass the movie's with out the 'box_office' or this error?

Thanks!

```
df_list1 = []

for movie_html in os.listdir(folder):
    with open(os.path.join(folder, movie_html)) as file: 
            soup = BeautifulSoup(file,'lxml')
            release_date = soup.find_all('div', class_='meta-value')[4].find('time').contents[0]
            box_office = soup.find_all('div', class_='meta-value')[6].contents[0].replace('$','').replace(',','')
            runtime = soup.find_all('div', class_='meta-value')[7].find('time').contents[0].strip()[:-len(" minutes")]
            studio = soup.find_all('div', class_='meta-value')[8].find('a').contents[0]

            df_list.append({[![enter image description here][1]][1]
                             'box_office':box_office,
                             'run_time': int(runtime),
                             'studio':studio
                        })
        
        


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yopG5.png
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a try-except block:

```
try:
    box_office = soup.find_all('div', class_='meta-value')[6].contents[0].replace('$','').replace(',','')
except AttributeError:
    box_office = None
```

Read more in the python docs [Errors and Exceptions | Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)